# Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions Error at OffScreenPageLimit() in ViewPager

Tags: android

I have made A View Pager inside a Fragment, it all Works fine, But whenever I set OffScreenPageLimit() For my pager, i get this Error :

```
 08-03 13:53:15.506: E/AndroidRuntime(5106): Process: com.lifemate.lmmessenger, PID:   
5106
08-03 13:53:15.506: E/AndroidRuntime(5106): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive 
entry to executePendingTransactions
08-03 13:53:15.506: E/AndroidRuntime(5106):     at     
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1450)
08-03 13:53:15.506: E/AndroidRuntime(5106):     at  
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.
executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:    478)
08-03 13:53:15.506: E/AndroidRuntime(5106):     at  
android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.jav    a:163)
08-03 13:53:15.506: E/AndroidRuntime(5106):     at 
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-03 13:53:15.506: E/AndroidRuntime(5106):     at 
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-03 13:53:15.506: E/AndroidRuntime(5106):     at 
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:695)
```

Here my Code:

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs_allinone);
    pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_allinone);
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());


    Sidepanel();

    RDbhelper = new RoomsDBhelper(getActivity());
    mDb = RDbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    final int pageMargin = (int) 
    TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics());
    pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);

    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
```

any Idea Why is this Happening guys?